I am getting an error while trying to import 'thunk' from 'redux-thunk'
I am new to React and Redux, and I am trying to build a webapp (authentication system) using React and Django.
I am following a tutorial to do that, with this github directory.
When I try to import thunk in Store.js from 'redux-thunk', it is returning me the following error on main page for React App (localhost:3000):
ERROR in ./src/Store.js 8:20-25
export 'default' (imported as 'thunk') was not found in 'redux-thunk' (possible exports: thunk, withExtraArgument)
I have tried using '{  thunk }', this approach is giving me black page on main React App (localhost:3000).
Code:
Store.js
import { legacy_createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import MainReducer from "./reducer/MainReducer";

const initialState = {}

const middleware = [thunk]

const Store = legacy_createStore(
    MainReducer,
    initialState,
    composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
);

export default Store;

Hompage of Redux App was expected if the import of thunk would have been successful, as shown in this video at 14:27 timestamp.

Not sure why it might be working as displayed in the tutorial, it could be down to a change in the version of redux-thunk.
if you look at the repo for redux-thunk (https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk), they specify that thunk is a named import, and so should be: import { thunk } from 'redux-thunk'
When you get the black screen, are there any error messages in the browser console?

Hey @Skandog, I appreciate you responding to my question.
The problem is resolved.
You are correct, import { thunk } is the right way to import it. The problem was in files of babel and redux-thunk, if I remember correctly. I reinstalled them and it worked.
Also, in App.js, I mistakenly put "component" instead of "Component" in Routes, so correcting that too helped.

Well done for cracking it

Thank you. Also, I forgot, It works only when 'Redux DevTools' extension is running in browser. I don't know why can't it run without it. :D

I have just fixed the problem. So putting the procedure here if anyone faces the same issue.
import { thunk } from 'redux-thunk';
is the right way, indeed. The primary issue was that I did not have 'Redux DevTools' installed on my browser as an extension. I installed it and it solved the issue partially.
Then, in App.js, I mistakenly put "component" instead of "Component" in Routes, so correcting that too helped. I also re-installed packages that were involved in the development.
In a nutshell,

Install 'Redux DevTools' extension on your browser.
Try reinstalling / re-adding the packages, libraries involved and associated with the code blocks if not all of those involved in developing your software.
Be mindful of case-senstivity.

Without Redux DevTools running on browser, it given a blank page. I don't know why as I am a beginner.
P.S. It is not in production environment yet.
